# Why lfs couldn't use original host environment variables?

Tags: environment-variables, lfs

From the [lfs doc](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/downloads/stable/LFS-BOOK-7.1.pdf):

> The exec env -i.../bin/bash command in the  .bash_profile   replaces
>   the running shell with a new one with a completely   empty
>   environment, except for the  HOME,  TERM, and  PS1   variables. This
>   ensures that no unwanted and potentially   hazardous environment
>   variables from the host system leak   into the build environment. The
>   technique used here achieves the  goal of ensuring a clean
>   environment.

What case will cause that problem?

Is there any simple example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of variables which will change how the shell behaves, what programs are executed or can hook into new programs. Examples for some of the more problematic environment variables are `CDPATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `LD_PRELOAD`, `PATH`.

By resetting the environment you can ensure a clean and sane build environment without the need to take care/reset all kind of environment variables.

Comment: What you mean 'hook into new programs like CDPATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, LD_PRELOAD, PATH'? Thank you~

Comment: @sam as i said environment variables can control many things, like which shared libraries are loaded or which program gets executed if you are using an unqualified command etc. i'll rephrase that sentence